# ESP8266 Exception 28

Tags: esp8266

I has a sketch that startings a web server to show files in LittleFS. But when it is starting, it's crashing with Exception code 28.
My full code:

```
#include <FS.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <LittleFS.h>
FS* fileSystem = &LittleFS;
File uploadFile;
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handleRoot() {
  String lstemp = "<html>\
    <head>\
      <title>ESP8266 FS Browser</title>\
    </head>\
    <body>\
      <nav>\
        <a href=\"/fsinfo\">Disk Info</a>\
      </nav>\n";
  if ((server.hasArg("path") ? server.arg("path") : "/").endsWith("/")) {
    Dir dir = fileSystem->openDir(server.hasArg("path") ? server.arg("path") : "/");
    Serial.println("listing dir");
    while (dir.next()) {
      Serial.println(dir.fileName());
      if (dir.isFile()) {
        lstemp += "<a href='/?path=" + (server.hasArg("path") ? server.arg("path") : "/") + dir.fileName() + "'>" + dir.fileName() + "</a><br>\n";
      } else {
        lstemp += "<a href='/?path=" + (server.hasArg("path") ? server.arg("path") : "/") + dir.fileName() + "/'>" + dir.fileName() + "/</a><br>\n";
      }
    }
  } else {
    lstemp = "<html><head><title>ESP8266 FS Browser</title></head><body>You are viewing file now. Click <a href='/download?action=download?path=" + server.arg("path") + "'>here</a> to download\n<iframe src='/download?action=view?path=" + server.arg("path") + "'></iframe>";
  }
  lstemp += "</body></html>";
  server.send(200, "text/html", lstemp);
}

void handleFsInfo() {
  String fsinfotemp = "FS: LittleFS\nTotal size: ";
  FSInfo fs_info;
  LittleFS.info(fs_info);
  fsinfotemp += fs_info.totalBytes / 1000;
  fsinfotemp += " KB\nUsed: ";
  fsinfotemp += fs_info.usedBytes / 1000;
  fsinfotemp += "\nFree: ";
  fsinfotemp += (fs_info.totalBytes - fs_info.usedBytes) / 1000;
  server.send(200, "text/plain", fsinfotemp);
}

void handleUploadFile() {}
void handleDownloadFile() {
  if (server.arg("action") == "download") {
    server.chunkedResponseModeStart(200, "application/octet-stream");
  }
  if (server.arg("action") == "view") {
    server.chunkedResponseModeStart(200, "text/plain");
  }
  File downloadable = fileSystem->open(server.arg("path"), (char*)'r');
  while (downloadable.available()) {
    server.sendContent((char*)downloadable.read());
    Serial.write(downloadable.read());
  }
  server.chunkedResponseFinalize();
  downloadable.close();
}
void handleMkdir() {}
void handleRemove() {}
void handleRename() {}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin("MySSID", "MyPASSWORD");
  if (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi Connect Failed! Rebooting...");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }
  if (!fileSystem->begin()) {
    Serial.println("File system begin failed! Formatting LittleFS...");
    fileSystem->format();
    Serial.println("Done. Reboot ESP8266");
    while (1) {;}
  }
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.on("/fsinfo", handleFsInfo);
  server.on("/upload", handleUploadFile);
  server.on("/download", handleDownloadFile);
  server.on("/mkdir", handleMkdir);
  server.on("/rm", handleRemove);
  server.on("/rename", handleRename);
  
  if (MDNS.begin("esp8266-filehost")) {
    MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);
  }
  server.begin();
  
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
  MDNS.update();
}
```

Full exception code:

```
--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Exception (28):
epc1=0x40214c00 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000072 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffca0 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 0190
3ffffe30:  3ffee9c0 ffffffff 00000006 402123c6  
3ffffe40:  000052b4 00000430 3fff0924 40208bba  
3ffffe50:  3ffffea0 3ffeff78 00000000 40211400  
3ffffe60:  0000000a 3ffee9e4 4021439c 00000000  
3ffffe70:  3ffffecc 00000000 3ffee9c0 402059d4  
3ffffe80:  00000000 3ffeeb64 3ffffea0 4020f901  
3ffffe90:  00000000 3ffeeb64 3ffee9c0 40207732  
3ffffea0:  00000000 69006e6f 00000000 ffffffff  
3ffffeb0:  40211df2 00000001 00000000 00000000  
3ffffec0:  0023002f 00000000 00000000 68746170  
3ffffed0:  3ffeea00 04000000 00000000 40211400  
3ffffee0:  00000000 00000000 4bc6a7f0 3ffeed28  
3ffffef0:  3fffdad0 00000001 3fff0204 4021435e  
3fffff00:  00000000 00000000 3fff0b3c 401000e9  
3fffff10:  00000000 616f6c6e 00000000 402058fd  
3fffff20:  3fff04b4 3ffeea08 3ffee9c0 40207876  
3fffff30:  00000000 3ffeeb08 00000001 4020accf  
3fffff40:  000052ac 00000000 00000000 00000001  
3fffff50:  00000001 3ffee9e4 3fff04e8 3ffeed28  
3fffff60:  3fffdad0 3ffee9e4 3ffee9c0 402080a2  
3fffff70:  00000000 3ffeeb08 3ffeed14 4020adc4  
3fffff80:  00000000 00000000 00000001 401003ec  
3fffff90:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeed14 40208168  
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeed14 40211de0  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe85dc 40100ea5  
<<<stack<<<

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------
```

This crash happens when I added file download function, but I hasn't found an error. Global variables remaining 36% of RAM, but all temp String variables are freed after finishing function automatically. So chunk server sending is collecting a much of junk?

Comment: On line `if (server.arg("action") == "view")`, there is no route defined for `/view`.

Comment: BTW, for `(char*)'r'`, you can just use `"r"` which is a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can happen when converting char to char*.  The read function returns a char and at the end of c-strings it should always be null and when converting it is not.  Perhaps there is an error in this

Comment: Maybe mistake in this, but if I use server.sendContent(downloadable.read()), it will not compile, error about invalid conversion from char to char*, how fix it?